# Not able to create calendar events webhook

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, webhooks

I am trying to create a subscription for calendar events. But I am getting 400 error with message containing:

```
    "code": "InvalidRequest",
    "message": "Subscription validation request failed. Must respond with 200 OK to this request."
```

As per webhook validation doc my server should have received call on notificationUrl passed in subscription post body, which is not happening for some reason. I can confirm this same POST notificationUrl could be accessed by me and it accepts validationToken  as query param.

Can someone please help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed  to resolve after checking access logs. Validationtoken request was getting blocked with 415 error because my api was only accepting json. Ensured that it can also accept "text/plain" and it is now working.

Answer (score 2):

your service must respond to this validation request by returning the value of the validationtoken query string parameter as a plain-text response.

something like

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Listen()
        {

            if (Request.QueryString["validationToken"] != null)
            {
                var token = Request.QueryString["validationToken"];
                return Content(token, "plain/text");
            }
}
```